# Pathauto not workin

Tags: path-aliases

Suddenly I discover that [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) is not working for my website and generate urls like node/89 .
I didn't made any update or installed any new module that could interfer with it.
Have you any suggestion for that?

Comment: did you run cron ? without more information it's difficult to provide more help.

Comment: Sorry, but if there really is no reason for this behaviour, it is severe bug in pathauto, and shuldn't be reported here. But to be honest I believe it is not a bug in module, but something you did, or at least something that happened on your server. Sadly, there is no way for *us* to know what happened on *your* site.

Comment: I'm using a shared hosted service, i don't think that something has been changed on the server, the only things i did last days is to install Twitter module ( in uninstalled it later ) and to add site slogan for all languages i have .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double check to make sure your patterns didn't get wiped somehow. Or that pathauto is still switched on. Also, make sure token is enabled, as pathauto requires this running as well. Might be some simple places to start looking.

Comment: Pathauto is still checked on but the weired thing is that the list of fields on pattern is empty admin/config/search/path/patterns